# Too many buttons causing horizontal scrolling in Launchpad

Tags: launchpad

I created a new section and a custom button, however for admins, this is now causing horizontal scrolling on smaller screens.  The Content Editing section has two rows of three buttons each and then a final row of one button.  I'm wondering if there's a way for me to force that section to only display rows of two buttons each, so that I'd have more horizontal space for the new section and button?

Comment: Can you add screenshots to better demonstrate what you setup and see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for the item "**ContentEditing**" in **Core DB** **/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing** the number of icons/applications to be displayed in each row is specified in this item's **RowsNumber** field.

> You can control the number of items in each row for other groups as
> well, I mean Marketing Applications, Access Management, etc.

For example - If you update the "RowsNumber" field as 2 below, I guess this might be 3 in your instance.

[image]

Then your launchpad will be updated as below to display 2 items per row in the Content Editing group.

[image]

In Sitecore 8.2, it doesn't contain the "RowsNumber" logic, so navigate to the launchpad application view, **.\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\LaunchPad\Layouts\Renderings\LaunchBar.cshtml** and the logic might be common for all the groups including "Content Editing". So if you want to customize for any group then you can add a custom field in Sitecore item [I mean in ContentEditing item], get the value, and write your logic [actually this is implemented out-of-box in newer versions of Sitecore]. Or you can statically set the count as 2 for your ContentEditing group alone.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm, when I look at the ContentEditing item, I'm not seeing the Rowsnumber field or even the Data section.  I'm on 8.2.

Comment: Always version matters.. :) Updated the answer for the version 8.2 initial release as well.. hope this can be applied in your case, you can customize the LaunchBar.cshtml based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  It's too bad you actually have to edit Sitecore's code to do this now. :(

Comment: yes.:) but Sitecore introduced "RowsNumber" field in the recent versions, so this will be a temp fix until you upgrade your instance :)

Comment: I see, I though it was already in there prior to 8.2 and then it was removed in 8.2.  Good to know that it was actually added after 8.2!